# Error! mysqli_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm fairly new to **php** and trying out some "tutorials" floating around on the web. One problem I have run into is older tutorials on "*up-to-date*" **php/MySQL** platforms.

For instance:

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
        ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$list = array();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $article = new Article( $row );
  $list[] = $article;
}
```

Because `mysql_escape`.. is *deprecated*, I'm trying to replace it with `mysqli_escape_string($conn, $order)`. But i believe my `$st = $conn->prepare($sql)` is throwing monkey wrench in the mix.

Any suggestions/explanations?

Comment: PDO has a `quote` function. But you can't escape identifiers (column names) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're using PDO, so you should be using prepared queries anyway.

That said, prepared queries won't work for what you're trying to do. And in any case, `mysql_real_escape_string` WILL NOT SAVE YOU HERE.

Instead, you could try some custom escaping:

```
"... ORDER BY `".str_replace(array("`","\\"),"",$order)."` LIMIT ...";
```

Backticks are USEFUL! :p

Comment: @Gumbo Please demonstrate why not.

Comment: Oh, thought you were replacing `\`` with `\\\\`. However, `\`publicationDate DESC\`` is probably not the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Okay several issues:

- You can't mix `mysql_*` functions with PDO. I know it's confusing, because PHP has *three* different API's for MySQL. But you have to use one at a time.
- The escaping functions, including [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php), are only for escaping string literals and date literals. They don't do the right thing for column names.
- Your `$order` variable has *two* syntax elements: the column, and the direction. Even if you were to quote the column properly, you wouldn't want to include `DESC` inside the quotes.
- The direction (`ASC`/`DESC`) is an SQL keyword, so it does not go into quotes. Therefore there's no escaping possible to make it safe against SQL injection.

My solution to this is not to use quoting/escaping, but to use **whitelisting**.  And keep the sort column separate from the sort direction.

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate", $direction="DESC" ) {

    $columns = array("publicationDate"=>"publicationDate", "name"=>"authorName", "DEFAULT"=>"publicationDate");
    $directions = array("up"=>"ASC", "down"=>"DESC", "DEFAULT"=>"DESC");

    $order_column    = $columns[$order] ?: $columns["DEFAULT"];
    $order_direction = $directions[$direction] ?: $directions["DEFAULT"];

    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate 
        FROM articles
        ORDER BY $order_column $order_direction LIMIT :numRows";
    . . .
 }
```

Tip: I never use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` because it is such a dire performance killer. It's actually much better to run *two* queries, one to get a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` and the second to get the limited result set.
See tests at [To SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS or not to SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)